# jQuery Plugin with setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, settimeout

I'm working on my first jQuery plugin which is a simple countdown timer with an option to set the target date.  The goal is to get a plain text clock counting down to the provided target date & time.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to use setTimeout or setInverval within the plugin so it actually counts down.  Spent all day digging through stackoverflow and  other sources but couldn't find a solution, so apologies if I'm just not getting it.

Here's what I've got:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.clock = function( options ) {  

    // ESTABLISH DEFAULTS
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'target' : '07/21/2013 09:00:00', // mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {        

      // calculate milliseconds to target
      tarDate = new Date(settings.target);
      dateNow = new Date();
      amount  = tarDate.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
      delete dateNow;

      // set label
      label = settings.title;

      // generate output
      if(amount <= 0) {
        out = '000:00:00:00';
      } else {
        td = 0; th = 0; tm = 0; ts = 0; out = ''; // reset everything
        amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);         // kill the milliseconds
        td     = Math.floor(amount/86400);        // calculate days to target
        amount = amount%86400;                    // convert amount to days
        th     = Math.floor(amount/3600);         // calculate hours to target
        amount = amount%3600;                     // convert amount to hours
        tm     = Math.floor(amount/60);           // calculate minutes to target
        amount = amount%60;                       // convert amount to minutes
        ts     = Math.floor(amount)+1;            // calculate seconds to target

    out += (td<=99?'0':'') + (td<=9?'0':'') + td + ':';
    out += (th<=9?'0':'') + th + ':';
    out += (tm<=9?'0':'') + tm + ':';
    out += (ts<=9?'0':'') + ts;
      }

      // assemble and pump out to dom
      $(this).html(out);

      // set refresh rate
      ??????

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) for an interesting pattern for plugin authoring. Basically what you need to do is provide a "method" for updating your clock:

```
(function( $ ){

    function updateClock(element) {
        var settings = element.data("settings");
        // Your update logic goes here
    }

    $.fn.clock = function( options ) {  
        if ( options === 'update' )
            return updateClock(this);
        // Other methods, if any
        else if ( typeof options !== 'object' )
            throw 'Unknown method';

        // ESTABLISH DEFAULTS
        var settings = $.extend( {
            'target' : '07/21/2013 09:00:00', // mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
        }, options);

        // Save your settings for later access
        this.data("settings",settings);
```

Then, every time you want to update an element, you call it this way:

```
$(yourselector).clock("update");
```

(from outside; if `updateClock` is accessible from your scope, you can call it directly for efficiency. Just remember to wrap the element in `$()` if necessary)

Lastly, you have to configure `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. I would prefer setTimeout, because that will allow you to stop or restart your clock if necessary. Add this to the end of your updateClock, maybe preceeded by a check:

```
setTimeout(function() { updateClock(element); }, settings.refreshRate);
```

Comment: I can see how that would work but how would I get the plugin options passed into the updateClock function?  Is there a way to use setTimeout within the $.fn.clock?  Good article by the way, thanks for the link.

Comment: @codybuell see my updated answer. Basically, you save your options when creating the element, then retrieve them when calling methods, using the `data` function (can also be used to maintain state, if used in individual clocks). You can call your update funcion for the first time just after creating the element, and it will call `setTimeout` for you in the end. Or just call it directly, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

i believe you have to have setTimeout inside the function that needs to be called and have setTimeout call the function its in. then have a condition setup so once it reaches zero clearTimeout will go off http://jsfiddle.net/qUYQN/

Comment: I can make it work just fine as a javascript function but I'm not sure how to accomplish that within a jquery plugin.